# How to compile a C++ program with SDL2 on OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, sdl-2

This is a pretty noob question. Basically I can't seem to be able to compile a basic Hello World program on OSX (Yosemite) using the SDL2 external library.

I'm trying to do this on console, without the help of any IDEs. I already installed the SDL 2.0.3 and it is located on the `/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework` path.

My main file looks like this:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool init();
void close();

SDL_Window* gameWindow = NULL;
SDL_Surface* gameScreenSurface = NULL;

bool init()
{
    ...
}

void close()
{
    ...
}

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    if( !init() )
    {
        printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
      SDL_Delay( 2000 );
    }
    close();
    return 0;
}
```

And I also have a makefile (taken from an example I found somewhere) that looks like this:

```
CC = g++
LDFLAGS = -g -Wall

PROGNAME = doom
SOURCES = main.cpp
INCLUDES = 
OBJECTS = $(subst %.cc, %.o, $(SOURCES))
ROOTCFLAGS  := $(shell root-config --cflags)
ROOTLIBS    := $(shell root-config --libs)
ROOTGLIBS   := $(shell root-config --glibs)
ROOTLIBS    := $(shell root-config --nonew --libs)
CFLAGS      += $(ROOTCFLAGS)
LIBS        += $(ROOTLIBS)

all: doom

$(PROGNAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o doom $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

%.o : %.cc $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) ${CFLAGS} -c -g -o $@ $<
```

And that's about it. When I run `make`, I receive this response:

```
make: root-config: Command not found
make: root-config: Command not found
make: root-config: Command not found
make: root-config: Command not found
g++ -g -Wall -o doom  main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_CreateWindow", referenced from:
      init() in main-8b6fae.o
  "_SDL_Delay", referenced from:
      _main in main-8b6fae.o
  "_SDL_DestroyWindow", referenced from:
      close() in main-8b6fae.o
  "_SDL_GetError", referenced from:
      init() in main-8b6fae.o
  "_SDL_GetWindowSurface", referenced from:
      init() in main-8b6fae.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      init() in main-8b6fae.o
  "_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
      close() in main-8b6fae.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [doom] Error 1
```

So, can I get some guidance please? I'm a little lost on where to start. I have never compiled a program on OSX or any Unix-based OS before.

I searched for that root-config thing that I'm missing, and It seems that I have to install a library called Root. I did it. Uncompressed it on a directory, don't know where to go from there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's my sdl2 example, works on OSX, but I'm using CMake to build: https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/sdl2web

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The makefile you found has variables for the ROOT data analysis framework, and not for SDL2.

Try running

```
g++ $(sdl2-config --cflags) -g -Wall -o doom  main.cpp $(sdl2-config --libs)
```

to get started.

Answer (score 0):

As amitp said, you are trying to use compiler and linker flags for the ROOT framework. Try this instead:

```
CFLAGS  += -F/Library/Frameworks
LDFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks
LIBS    += -framework SDL2
```